# .getScanResults() returns the same objects

Tags: android, wifimanager

I am having an issue where when I call ".getScanResults()" the objects in the returned list are the same. I have tested this and have recorded the results to demonstrate.

> SSID: ####, BSSID: c0:c1:c0:ab:42:dc, capabilities: [WEP][ESS], level: -51, frequency: 2412, timestamp: 246825251245
>
> SSID: ####, BSSID: c0:c1:c0:ab:42:dc, capabilities: [WEP][ESS], level: -51, frequency: 2412, timestamp: 246825251245

Everything is exactly the same including the timestamp. My code is as follows.

```
public void checkNetwork(View view) {
    wifi_manager.startScan();

    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
}

class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) {

            List<ScanResult> wifi_scan_list = wifi_manager.getScanResults();

            int number_of_access_points = wifi_scan_list.size();

            for(int i = 0; i < number_of_access_points; i++) {
                String data = wifi_scan_list.get(i).toString();

                writeToFile(data + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            wifi_scan_list.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763397/how-to-synchronize-wifimanager-startscan-and-wifimanager-getscanresults, you might want to consider storing results in a `Set` so that duplicates are automatically pruned for you.

Comment: @stkent Thank you for your response. I tried changing the List to a Set however, the class doesn't allow that. Casting doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I wrote a fuller answer below; try that and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
List<ScanResult> wifi_scan_list = wifi_manager.getScanResults();
```

with

```
List<ScanResult> raw_wifi_scan_list = wifi_manager.getScanResults();
Set<ScanResult> unique_wifi_scan_set = new HashSet(raw_wifi_scan_list);
List<ScanResult> wifi_scan_list = new Arraylist(unique_wifi_scan_set);
```

This code:

1. retrieves the raw list of scan results;
2. [creates a new `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(java.util.Collection)) and adds all raw scan results to that set (thereby removing duplicates);
3. [creates a new `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) containing just the deduplicated scan results.

Without testing this I can't be 100% sure that the order of the original list will be preserved in the final list; however, from the rest of your code this does not seem to be critical to your use-case.